# Jquery ajax, send very big data base64, how optimize that

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So, i have a script for capture a video from webcam and after create a gif with :

```
var base64data;
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          var reader = new window.FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          reader.onloadend = function() {
            base64data = reader.result;
            img.src = base64data;
          }
```

So, with this script, i take the blob object from webcam, i encode this blob into base64 and i put the data into my `img.src`.

After that, i need to send this data into PHP with jquery ajax.

The base64data is very big, like 2 000 000 characters, so the ajax request is very long (20-50sec).

I just send the data like that :

```
var gif = $('.generated-img').attr('src').replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '');        
    gif = gif.match(/.{1,500000}/g);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/webcam/",
        data: {image_gif:gif, crop_x:x, crop_y:y, crop_w:w, crop_h:h, gif:true},
        success: function () {
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
        }
    });
```

I need to break the data into several chunks of 500 000 characters each.

But it's soooo long.. How can i do for optimize that ? I just need to retrieve this data into my php script for do some stuff...

Comment: 2MB image? thats big.. I would resize it somehow, using `<canvas>` for that and sending it up via [getImageData](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/canvas_getimagedata.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly why you need to split it up;  the idea of using AJAX - where A stands for asynchronous - is precisely that you can do big slow things in the background.

But rather than using a regular expression to do the split, I would just break it up using substr, e.g.  something like (not tested, so may be offset errors - e.g. you may need a `+ 1` or `- 1` here and there):

```
 var chunkSize = 500000;
 var chunkId = 0;
 var isLastChunk = false;
 for(var i = 0; i < gif.length; i += chunkSize)
 {
    var chunk;
    if(gif.length > i + chunkSize) {
      chunk = gif.substr(0, i, chunkSize);
    } else {
      chunk = gif.substr(0, i);
      isLastChunk = true;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/webcam/",
        data: {
          chunk: chunk, chunkId: chunkId, isLastChunk: isLastChunk,
          crop_x:x, crop_y:y, crop_w:w, crop_h:h, gif:true},
        success: function () {
           // Chunk handled succesfully
        }
    });
 }
```

In `/webcam/` you could check `chunkId`, and `isLastChunk`.

Comment: He probably splits the data to stand against PHP execution time? unless he can handle that too